# Simple code to show custom content with cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm a designer not a programmer and after days of googling I have to turn here for help. I'm sure this is fairly simple for a programmer. What I need is a code that lets users select check-boxes to set cookies that will display corresponding images on the page.

For example a checkbox form with options [a] [b] [c], if a user selects boxes [a] and [c] then a cookie will be set and display somewhere on the page

`<img src="a.gif"> <img src="c.gif">`

If the user goes back to the form and selects different options then other images will be displayed. Basically this script is to allow users to customize certain parts of the page based on options available to them. Cookies should not expire so users can comeback to their custom page. I need it to be in javascript, preferably using jQuery if it will simplify the code since I already load jQuery for other functions.

I applied your code but it doesn't create a cookie. What am I missing in html code?

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourcookiecode.js"></script>

</head>

<BODY>
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="a" onClick="SetCookie('name', this.name, exp);">
<input type="checkbox" name="b" onClick="SetCookie('name', this.name, exp);">
<input type="checkbox" name="c" onClick="SetCookie('name', this.name, exp);">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATED CODE:

See: http://jsfiddle.net/87H7s/2/

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a">
<input type="checkbox" name="b">
<input type="checkbox" name="c">

<div id="somediv"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(':checkbox').each( function(){
         //Search if checkbox exist in cookie
        var checkbox = $(this);
         var getname = checkbox.attr('name');
         var searchCookie = $.cookie(getname);

        if(searchCookie != null) {
         //Was in div, now add img
            $(':checkbox[name*="'+getname+'"]').attr('checked',true);
            $('#somediv').append('<img src="'+getname+'.gif" />');
        }
    });


    $(':checkbox').change( function() {
        var checkbox = $(this);
        var isChecked = checkbox.is(':checked');
        var getname = checkbox.attr('name');
        if(isChecked) {
         //Add to cookie, add img
             $.cookie(getname, 'true', { expires: 7 });   
             $('#somediv').append('<img src="'+getname+'.gif" />');
        } else {
         //Unchecked, remove from cookie
            $('#somediv').find('img[src*="'+getname+'"]').remove();
            $.cookie(getname, null);
        }
    });
});
```

---

You need the cookie plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

And then you could do something like:

```
$(:checkbox).each( function(){
     //Search if checkbox exist in cookie
     var getname = checkbox.attr('name');
     var searchCookie = $.cookie(getname);

    if(searchCookie != null) {
     //Was in div, now add img
        $('#somediv').append('<img src="'+getname+'.gif" />');
    }
});


$(:checkbox).change( function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);
    var isChecked = checkbox.is(':checked');

    if(isChecked) {
         var getname = checkbox.attr('name');
     //Add to cookie, add img
         $.cookie(getname, 'true', { expires: 7 });   
         $('#somediv').append('<img src="'+getname+'" />');
    } else {
     //Unchecked, remove from cookie
        $.cookie(getname, null);
    }
});
```

Comment: I wonder if you can figure out how to make this script work with a jQuery dock I'm trying to use it with. It has mouse proximity effects. I spent 3 days with no progress. Sample here http://acerx.net/test/test.htm  shows how it works with normal images and how it behaves with images from checkbox cookie script. Also there are comments in source code where I think the problem is.

Comment: Do you want it so you can choose a smiley, by clicking on one of the images in the list?

Comment: No, I'm just trying to get the mouse proximity effect working with images from your script. Like in the demo I made here http://acerx.net/test/test.htm Still no success

Comment: Still dont understand what you want to happen :/

Comment: In the example I made to show you here http://acerx.net/test/test.htm on top of the page see the jQuery mouseover effect on the smileys, you move the mouse closer to the icon and it gets bigger. Now when I try to do the same effect with the images inserted using the cookie script you helped me with, the mouseover effect doesn't work. I made an example below on that page. What happens is the smiley icons just overlap each other. This is what I'm struggling to fix. I don't know how.

Comment: First off the "fisheye" plugin isn't added to the cookie image - because you use #dock twice, and the same ID can only be used ONCE on a page, so the second one(the cookie part) is ignored. Seconed the "fisheye" plugin binds on pageload, and since the cookie image is loaded afterwards - it isn't binded. So you should use "live" instead of bind - which binds it global to the element.. Couldnt you just display the images normally - add fisheye - read cookie and make do whatever you want with the active smiley?

Comment: As you suggested I removed second instance of #dock and changed "bind" to "live" in 3 places. There is one more place where I kept "bind" because fisheye stops working when I changed it to "live".  But it still overlaps the smileys. I updated the htm file so you can see the changes.  You said display images normally, how can I do that and keep the check-box feature (which is a necessary function) for adding and removing icons. The script you gave me in the beginning works perfectly, I just want it to have a cool effect that fisheye does.

Comment: You said "fisheye" plugin binds on pageload, and since the cookie image is loaded afterwards - it isn't binded. Then can the fisheye plugin be loaded after the images? With something like this $('#book').load(function() {
  // Handler for .load() called.
});

Comment: here's where I test it http://acerx.net/test/test.htm The only issue is when you remove the smiley, then add it back you have to refresh page for it display properly again. I don't know yet how to fix that. The changes I made was in your script and in fisheye is "$(window).load(function()" to "$(window).ready(function()"

Comment: It's becasue when Fisheye loads it dosent contain any images - so it sets width to "0" - which means any images inside will get hidden. Then on page reload it contains an image and sets the correct width. So you could either have a blank image as a starting point, or "recall" the fisheye function on checkbox.change :)